# PHP : How to use dynamic variables

Tags: php, sendmail

I'm trying to send HTML email from my Custom Controller.

Here's code.

```
public function execute()
{
    $to = "dev@test.com";
    $subject = "HTML email";

    $message = "
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>HTML email</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>'.$_POST["company_name"].'</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
            ";


    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>';

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

**How Can I use dynamic variables based on POST request so that Email Send perfectly with Dynamic form.**

I've tried as I paste above code but still getting syntax erros in PHP Strom.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest doing a print_r($_POST) to see all the variables you have, you probably need the $to variable to be read from POST.
Also, this line             <td>'.$_POST["company_name"].'</td>
you need double quotes, like this:   <td>".$_POST["company_name"]."</td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<td>'.$_POST["company_name"].'</td>
```

use:

```
<td>".$_POST['company_name']."</td>
```

Your HTML is quoted with double quotation so to return to PHP you also need to use double one.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. For multiline strings, I'd recommend using [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Secondly, save the form data into a variable before using it in the string.

```
$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];

$message = <<<EOD
<html>
<h1>$company_name</h1>
<html>
EOD;
```

Comment: Yes to heredoc for multiline string. Personally, unless I’m going to use the value elsewhere, I find storing it as a variable to be unnecessary and a bit wasteful. There’s other options, such as dot concatenation or curly braces, for parsing a post/session/array value.